# How to present a div only when the index.php is accessed for/by the single post pages

Tags: php, single

Suppose there is a div →

```
<div class="only-single-page">
  some code
</div>
```

How to make sure that this div is there only when the index.php is accessed for the Posts single pages.

```
<?php  If is_single() { ?>
     <div class="only-single-page">
      some code
    </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

But it didn't worked.

Comment: It should give syntax error right now, because it should be `if (is_single()) {` to be PHP correct.

Comment: Let me try that version. I will update you.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Please update your answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. Write the condition as:

```
if (is_single()) {
  your code here
}
```

Comment: Note, this will also apply to custom post types. If you want a check for a single Post and no other post type, change your conditional to `if ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post' )`

Comment: I have upvoted you and accepted the answer. If you think this was a good question then please upvote me too.